# Can any number of the form $2p$, for $p>3$ a prime, be written as the sum of two distinct primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

I think Goldbach's conjecture is quite well-know at this point, but there is no problem restating it: any even integer greater than $2$ can be written as the sum of two prime numbers.

But what about distinct prime numbers? For every even integer $n$ that does not equal $2p$, for $p$ a prime, Goldbach's conjecture obviously implies that $n$ can be written as the sum of two distinct prime numbers, but the question in the title remains: what if $n=2p$? (Ignore $p=3$, which clearly fails...)

I tested all prime numbers up to 10.000.000 and found no exceptions.

Comment: You may want to refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135902/a-slightly-stronger-version-of-the-goldbach-conjecture

Comment: @dust05 I didn't see that question before posting mine, shame... I will probably delete mine, given it is a duplicate.